# PHP Array Intersection

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, array-intersect

Maybe someone can help me find the array intersection of a multidemsional array like this one:

```
[attributes] => Array
                (
                    [Color] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Cool White
                            [1] => Warm White
                        )

                    [LED Amount] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 30 LEDs
                        )

                )

[FILTER] => Array
                (
                    [Color] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Warm White
                        )

                )
```

I have tried the following code, but the problem is the multi-dimensional array.

`$intersection = array_intersect($arry['FILTER'], $arry['attributes']);`

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You could loop through the `attributes` array.

Comment: Do you have to find the intersection of all attributes or just color?

Comment: I have to find the intersection of all attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this function [array_uintersect_assoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-uintersect-assoc.php)